# How to search from relationship data ? In laravel

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent, model, laravel-4

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $value)
{
    $searchValues = explode(' ', $value);
    if (!$value) return $query;
    return $query->where(function ($q) use ($searchValues) {
        foreach ($searchValues as $token) {
            $q->orWhere('name', 'like', "%{$token}%");
            $q->orWhere('street', 'like', "%{$token}%");
        }
    });
}
```

I want to search the data. This model also has

```
public function brands()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Brand::class, 'dealer_brands');
}
public function province()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Province::class);
}
```

How can I get data from the relastionship. Like Dealer(model) has data Nmae = josh ,  brand_id = 1 {brand.name = samsung} , province_id = 2 (province.name = "aligora"). When I search Josh Samsung Alogora, I want to ge the data. When I only search aligora, I want to get the data of model having  province aligora. hOW CAN I MODIFY CODE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at your model relationships. This may work for you

```
    public function scopeSearch($query, $value)
    {
        if (!$value) return $query;
        $searchValues = explode(' ', $value);
        return $query->where(function ($q) use ($searchValues) {
            foreach ($searchValues as $token) {
                $q->where('name', 'like', "%{$token}%")
                    ->orWhere('street', 'like', "%{$token}%")
                    ->orWhereHas('brands', function ($sub_q) use ($searchValues) {
                        $sub_q->where('name', 'like', "%{$token}%")
                            ->orWhere('street', 'like', "%{$token}%");
                    })
                    ->orWhereHas('province', function ($sub_q) use ($searchValues) {
                        $sub_q->where('name', 'like', "%{$token}%")
                            ->orWhere('street', 'like', "%{$token}%");
                    });
            }
        });
    }
```

I have no idea about column names in related tables so repeating name and street. you can change as per requirement

Comment: I tried modifying code to whis, but it says Unknown column 'brands' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `dealers`. Dealer(Model) has belongstomany relastioship with brand and belongTo with province. How can I modify that ?

Comment: sorry there was mistake in code using 'orwhere'. please check now again I have changed it to 'orWhereHas' for relationship query.